# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.RegionTooBusyException

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to load **3 billion** records(ORC file) from hive to Hbase using hive-HBase integration.

Hive Create table DDL

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cs.account_dim_hbase(`account_number` string,`encrypted_account_number` string,`affiliate_code` string,`alternate_party_name` string, `alternate_party_name` string) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,account_dim:encrypted_account_number,account_dim:affiliate_code,account_dim:alternate_party_name")TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "default:account_dim");
```

Hive Insert Query to HBase, I am running 128 insert command similar to the below example.

```
insert  into table cs.account_dim_hbase  select account_number ,encrypted_account_number ,    affiliate_code ,alternate_party_name,mod_account_number from cds.account_dim where mod_account_number=1;
```

When I try to run all 128 inserts at the same time I am getting the below error

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 438 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.RegionTooBusyException: Over memstore limit=2.0G, regionName=jhgjhsdgfjgsdjf, server=cldf0007.com
```

Help me to fix this and let me know If am doing anything wrong. I am using HDP 3

Answer (score 0):

Loaded the data from hive using MD5 Hashing on the rowkey field and created the HBASE table using region splits. Now the data gets loaded just in 5 min per partition (It was 20 min before with exceptions but now fixed)

```
create ‘users, ‘usercf’, SPLITS=›
['10000000000000000000000000000000',
'20000000000000000000000000000000',
'30000000000000000000000000000000',
'40000000000000000000000000000000',
'50000000000000000000000000000000',
'60000000000000000000000000000000',
'70000000000000000000000000000000',
'80000000000000000000000000000000',
'90000000000000000000000000000000',
'a0000000000000000000000000000000',
'b0000000000000000000000000000000',
'c0000000000000000000000000000000',
'd0000000000000000000000000000000',
'e0000000000000000000000000000000',
'f0000000000000000000000000000000']
```